# Question about negative Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Is it true that, if $a^2-Db^2=-1$ is solvable in integers, then so is $x^2-Dy^2=D$ (*)?

For $D=5$ this is true, you can take $x=5$ and $y=2$, and indeed $5^2-5(2^2)=5$, so (*) is solvable. Is this true in general?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem, and what have you tried?  You can use relatively basic algebra here to find such a solution (try to arrange things such that you can pull a factor of $D$ out of the quadratic), but I don't want to give the game away if this is an exercise...

Comment: I showed this at your previous question, I suppose i was assuming $D$ squarefree.

Comment: @WillJagy to go this direction you don't need the squarefreeness at all.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I invented this problem myself. I was trying to transform negative Pell into a positive one through linear substitution.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, it was the other direction;

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: So if $a^2-Db^2=-1$, we rearrange to get $a^2+1=Db^2$, and multiplying by $D$ gives $D(a^2+1)=(Db)^2$, and rearranging yields $(Db)^2-Da^2=D$.

Answer (score 1):

Standard fact in Gaussian composition, or more precisely Dirichlet composition. If the principal form of a discriminant integrally represents $-1,$ then it is *equivalent* to its own negative, and every form of that discriminant represents some integer $k$ if and only if it represents $-k.$ You had the substitution correct in your other question, if $u^2 - n v^2 = -1,$ then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & v \\
nv & u
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -n
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & nv \\
v & u
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & n
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It is true that the transformation matrix on the right,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & nv \\
v & u
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has determinant $-1,$ but we can just negate one row or one column to get determinant $1$ and it still works. For example,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & v \\
-nv & -u
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -n
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & -nv \\
v & -u
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & n
\end{array}
\right)
$$ and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & -nv \\
v & -u
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has determinant $+1.$